# Why does OS X require admin privileges to unmount a drive from the terminal using `umount` but not when using Finder?

Tags: macos, filesystem

Anyone can unmount a usb drive from Finder by clicking on the "eject" icon next to it.  However, only a user with administrative privileges can unmount a drive from the terminal using `umount`.

Are `umount` and "eject" different in some way that requires more security for `umount` from the terminal?

<sub>Note I am running OS X 10.8.2</sub>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`umount` is a UNIX command that adheres to the traditional UNIX perspective that unmounting a filesystem is a **system administration task**.

The rationale behind is that unmounting a filesystem, if poorly planned or executed, could be disruptive, even destructive, especially on a multiuser system. So regular users are protected from this potentially dangerous command and only [root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_user) or a privileged user is allowed to execute it.

This makes a lot of sense when UNIX is used as a server operating system, but a UNIX-based desktop OS (for example, OS X or [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)) has other needs: any user should be able to unmount flash drives, removable harddrives, etc.

The Finder and `diskutil` (see [man diskutil](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8) for more information) work this way. For example, I can open Terminal and successfully run:

```
$ diskutil unmount /Volumes/Untitled
Volume Untitled on disk2s2 unmounted
```

whereas `umount` fails:

```
$ umount /Volumes/Untitled
umount: unmount(/Volumes/Untitled): Operation not permitted
```

What is the Finder or `diskutil` doing differently? Behind the scenes, they send a request to a [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) called **com.apple.SecurityServer** (see [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8) for more information), which grants the right to unmount the filesystem:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/system.log
Feb  6 16:57:37 avallone.local com.apple.SecurityServer[17]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.volume.removable.unmount' by client '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' [171] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' [171] (100013,0)
Feb  6 16:57:37 avallone.local com.apple.SecurityServer[17]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.volume.removable.unmount' by client '/usr/sbin/diskarbitrationd' [18] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' [171] (100002,0)
Feb  6 17:01:46 avallone.local com.apple.SecurityServer[17]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.volume.removable.unmount' by client '/usr/sbin/diskutil' [646] for authorization created by '/usr/sbin/diskutil' [646] (100013,0)
Feb  6 17:01:46 avallone.local com.apple.SecurityServer[17]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.volume.removable.unmount' by client '/usr/sbin/diskarbitrationd' [18] for authorization created by '/usr/sbin/diskutil' [646] (100002,0)
```

This allows any user to unmount a drive without requiring additional authentication. (Ubuntu has a similar philosophy. If you are interested, take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405/why-do-i-need-root-privileges-to-umount-a-drive-at-the-command-line-but-not-in) on AskUbuntu.)

To support the behavior explained above the Finder and `diskutil` use several Apple frameworks:

```
$ otool -L $(which diskutil) | grep Disk
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskManagement.framework/Versions/A/DiskManagement (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
$ otool -L /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder | grep Disk
/System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Versions/A/DiskImages (compatibility version 1.0.8, current version 344.0.0)
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskManagement.framework/Versions/A/DiskManagement (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

`umount`, on the other side, is only linked to this dynamic library:

```
$ otool -L $(which umount) 
/sbin/umount:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

(`/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` uses several other libraries, but isn't linked to any framework.)

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks.  I came to mac from linux so I didn't know about `diskutil`. That is good knowledge to have.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I could help to shed some light on the differences between `umount` and `diskutil`/Finder.