# Cannot mount UDF formatted hard disk in OSX

Tags: unix, macos, mount

I have formated a 2TB external disk with UDF filesystem in Ubuntu. The way I formatted it was:

```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=2048 count=1
   sudo mkudffs --media-type=hd --vid=myDisk --blocksize=2048 /dev/sdc
```

Now I plug the disk in OSX and nothing is automount. The disk is recognized, but nothing else, it's not mounted. I am in OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

`diskutil list` shows:

```
 /dev/disk2
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
 0:                                                   *2.0 TB     disk2
```

So first problem is that it doesn't recognize the TYPE NAME is defined in format option (--vid=myDisk). Anyway....

I tried to mount the disk manually:

```
   sudo mkdir /Volumes/myDisk
   sudo mount -v -t udf /dev/disk2 /Volumes/myDisk/
```

And I get:

```
 mount_udf: /dev/disk2 on /Volumes/myDisk: Device not configured
```

If I try:

```
 diskutil mount  -mountPoint /Volumes/myDisk /dev/disk2
```

I get

```
 Volume on disk2 failed to mount; if it has a partitioning scheme, use "diskutil mountDisk"
```

If I try:

```
 sudo mount_udf -b 2048  /dev/disk2 /Volumes/myDisk/
```

I get

```
   mount_udf: /dev/disk2 on /Volumes/myDisk/: Device not configured
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: is this of any help ? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81131/why-does-os-x-require-admin-privileges-to-unmount-a-drive-from-the-terminal-usin

Comment: You didn't partition the disk, that is, you created the filesystem on `/dev/sdc` instead of `/dev/sdc1`. Not sure if that's a problem on OS X, but you may want to create a partition `/dev/sdc1`, create the UFS filesystem and try again.

Answer (score 1):

## Details:

> I have formated a 2TB external disk with UDF filesystem in Ubuntu. The way I formatted it was:
>
> ```
> sudo mkudffs --media-type=hd --vid=myDisk --blocksize=2048 /dev/sdc
> ```

This UDF partition on your external disk would not be readable by any non-Linux system. Requirement of UDF filesystem is that disk's *logical block size* must match *UDF filesystem block size*.

All hard disks and SSD, including external disks have logical block size of 512 bytes. Note that new disks have *physical* block size of 4096 bytes, but here is  relevant just *logical*. CD/DVD/BD optical discs have logical block size of 2048 bytes, so you probably thought that settings for optical discs would work also for hard disks...

> So first problem is that it doesn't recognize the TYPE NAME is defined in format option (--vid=myDisk).

Volume label for UDF filesystem is defined by *Logical Volume Identifier* which is configured by *--lvid* option in mkudffs.

What you need is to re-format your disk again with correct *--blocksize* and ideally specify also *--lvid* for label.

New version 2.0 of mkudffs now automatically set *--blocksize* to the logical block size. And it also supports option *--label* which sets correct parameters for volume label.

For more information about compatibility of UDF, mkudffs and other operating systems looks into mkudffs 2.0+ manpage into section COMPATIBILITY and BLOCK SIZE.

## Summary:

To format hard disk correctly with mkudffs prior to 1.1 you should do:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M count=10
sudo mkudffs --blocksize=512 --lvid="label" --vid="label" /dev/sdc
```

With mkudffs version 1.1+ you should just do:

```
sudo mkudffs --label="label" /dev/sdc
```

If you want your hard disk to be readable also by Windows systems then you need to use at least mkudffs version 2.0.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/a/1285180